# On which system can be done whole process of developing application in qt for ios/android with bluetooth/http functions

Tags: android, ios, qt, google-play, app-store

I need to write application for iPhone and android phone.
My goals are:
- put application into app-store and google- play,
- Bluetooth communication, cause it would control some devices via blue tooth ( send / get data) 
- http/ socket communication

[What I think that I know]

I make some research and I figure out that there is no option to make full development process on windows.It's impossible to create package for app store without xcode which isn't available  on windows. Bluetooth for ios which "must be" in me app isn't supported in qt  [source](https://forum.qt.io/topic/46529/bluetooth-on-ios-android/2) . The tutorial on the web which I found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFGRr0DV3oM) is made on os x system. [Here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/28095/developing-ios-under-windows/10) I read that I would need to move to os x to develop native part.  So for testing, compiling, and using some emulator I propably also need osx.

QUESTION

So to make whole process of developing, I mean:

- writing code in c++ and native languages ( jave/xcode),
- testing it on emulators of iPhone/ Android phone,
- generating package for android and ios to put it on the stores.

all this things, without changing platforms,  can be done in qt only on os x , not on windows, am I right? Or maybe something change by today because my sources can be outdated ? What I think right now is that the only option for me is using virtual box with os x and qt on it.

If you have any other ideas/sources/advice to do this, just give me a word, I would be gratefulcause right now I'm lost.

Comment: As you already assumed, you'll need OS X for iOS development. So this boils down to "what options do I have to run OS X".